# how to filter a many-to-many fied?django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, manytomanyfield

example:

```
class Person(model.Models)
  name = model.CharField(max_length=30)
  age = model.IntegerField()
class Book(model.Model)
  title = model.CharField(max_length=30)
  author = model.ManyToManyField(Person)

per1 = Person('Jack',10)
per1.save
per2 = Person('Rose',20)
per2.save
book1 = Book()
book1.title = 'booktitle'
book1.author.add(per1)
book1.author.add(per2)
```

now I want to get the 'book1' obj like this

```
{
  'title':'booktitle',
  'author':[
       {
         'name':'Jack',
         'age':10,
      }
   ]
}
```

there is noly one author in the 'book1' obj
how to filter the related field?
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Book.objects.filter(author="Jack").all()
```

You can also filter on multiple authors:

```
Book.objects.filter(author=["Jack", "Rose"]).all()
```

Comment: thanks. But I want to get the 'book1' obj,with only one author.  \n I want to filter the author model but not the book model.   Just like the limit_choices_to do.

Comment: Your answer can get the 'book1' with two author,Now i just need one.  Maybe I'm just not accurate description，the 'book1' obj has two author , I want to get it with just one author by some conditions.

Comment: Than you can use the first example?

Comment: The first example will get data like this {'title':'booktitle',
  'author':[
       {
         'name':'Jack',
         'age':10,
      } , { 'name':'Rose','age':10,}
   ]
} . But what i want is like this {'title':'booktitle',
  'author':[
       {
         'name':'Jack',
         'age':10,
      }
   ]
}.I want to get 'book1' obj with one author....